# Angular - how to create separate "ViewContainerRef" Containers for different tabs in mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, runtimemodification

I am creating runtime component module with dynamic component by binding html data and functions to it, which i am fetching from api call, as string data.
And then loading the newly generated component to my container, placed in the tabs, as i am creating the tabs dynamically as per the data. The process is working for first tab, but not for other tabs.

That may mean, the container, where i am pushing my runtime component, is generated once, thus not reflecting for other tabs.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (selectedTabChange)="getNewTabFields($event)">
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.displayName">
        <div *ngIf="errorOccured" class="text-align-center"> No Data Found! </div>
        <ng-container #container></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
ngOnInit() {
this.templateInitial = 
this.searchConfig.configurations[0].value.resultView;
this.query = this.searchConfig.configurations[6].value.queryParams;          
this.collectionName = 
this.searchConfig.configurations[6].value.collectionName;
this.loadSearchData();
}
compileTemplate() {
const metadata = {
  selector: `runtime-component`,
  template: this.templateInitial
};
const _mydata = this.solrResponse.response.docs;
const code: string =  this.searchConfig.configurations[1].value['logic'];
const result: string = ts.transpile(code);
const runnalbe: any = eval(result);
const compileClass = class RuntimeComponent {
  solrResponses = _mydata;
  presentLogic = runnalbe;
};

const factory = this.createComponentFactorySync(this.compiler, metadata, compileClass );
if (this.componentRef) {
  this.container.remove(this.container.indexOf(this.componentRef));
  this.componentRef = undefined;
}
this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}

private createComponentFactorySync(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component, componentClass: any): ComponentFactory<any> {
const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(componentClass);

@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
class RuntimeComponentModule { }

const module: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any> = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(RuntimeComponentModule);
this.componentInstance = module.componentFactories.find((f) => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
return module.componentFactories.find((f) => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
}
 getNewTabFields(event) {
this.tabIndex = event.index;
this.constructTabData(this.tabIndex);
}
constructTabData(i) {
this.templateInitial = this.tabs[i].configurations.resultView;
this.query = this.tabs[i].configurations.query[0].queryParams;
this.collectionName = this.tabs[i].configurations.query[0].queryParams['collection'].split(' ')[0];
this.loadSearchData();
}
loadSearchData(_row = 10, _start = 0) {

this.solrSearchService.getSolrData(this.query, this.collectionName).subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.solrResponse = [];
    this.solrResponse = JSON.parse(data);
    this.compileTemplate();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use for creating these containers the directive.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (selectedTabChange)="getNewTabFields($event)">
    <div *ngIf="errorOccured" class="text-align-center"> No Data Found! </div>
    <ng-container myDirective *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [tab]="tab"></ng-container>
</mat-tab-group>
```

My directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  tab: MyTamComponent;


  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private container: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<MyTamComponent>(MyTamComponent);
    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);

    // other stuff
    component.instance.label = tab.displayName;
    component.instance.ref = component;
  }

}
```